# Alternative to switch with non-constant

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I just learned that a switch statement can't use non-constant conditions. Which is fine and all, I get it. But does that really mean I have to make a big if-else block? It's so ugly I'm crying.

Some context: I'm doing a Unity project and I want to switch on the current animation state. A good way to check the current animation state is to compare hashes, which means I need to calculate the hashes for the animation state. After calculating them I want to switch on them. (Writing this I realized I can paste the resulting hash into a constant, but now I still want an answer)

```
int state1 = Animator.StringToHash("State1");
int state2 = Animator.StringToHash("State2");
int hash = _myAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).shortNameHash;
switch (hash):
{
case state1:
    //DoStuff
    break;
case state2:
    //Other stuff
    break;
}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Are hashes in your context even unique? Seems dangerous.

Comment: Why not define your state as an `Enum` or even simply an `int`. What's the reason to hash the state? States should be pretty well defined, especially if you're writing a switch statement for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a dictionary.

Try this:

```
int state1 = Animator.StringToHash("State1");
int state2 = Animator.StringToHash("State2");
int hash = _myAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).shortNameHash;
var cases = new Dictionary<Func<bool>, Action>()
{
    { () => hash == state1, () => { /* Do stuff */} },
    { () => hash == state2, () => { /* Do other stuff */} },
};

cases
    .Where(c => c.Key()) // find conditions that match
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Value) //select the `Action`
    .FirstOrDefault() // take only the first one
    ?.Invoke(); // Invoke the action only if not `null`
```

---

To make it a little more clean you could define a `Switch` class like this:

```
public class Switch : IEnumerable<Switch.Case>
{
    private List<Case> _list = new List<Case>();

    public void Add(Func<bool> condition, Action action)
    {
        _list.Add(new Case(condition, action));
    }

    IEnumerator<Case> IEnumerable<Case>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        this
            .Where(c => c.Condition())
            .Select(c => c.Action)
            .FirstOrDefault()
            ?.Invoke();
    }

    public sealed class Case
    {
        private readonly Func<bool> _condition;
        private readonly Action _action;

        public Func<bool> Condition { get { return _condition; } }
        public Action Action { get { return _action; } }

        public Case(Func<bool> condition, Action action)
        {
            _condition = condition;
            _action = action;
        }
    }
}
```

Then the code looks like this:

```
int state1 = Animator.StringToHash("State1");
int state2 = Animator.StringToHash("State2");
int hash = _myAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).shortNameHash;
var @switch = new Switch()
{
    { () => hash == state1, () => { /* Do stuff */} },
    { () => hash == state2, () => { /* Do other stuff */} },
};

@switch.Execute();
```

And if you write it like this it almost looks like a normal `switch` statement:

```
var @switch = new Switch()
{
    {
        () => hash == state1,
        () =>
        {
            /* Do stuff */
        }
    },
    {
        () => hash == state2,
        () =>
        {
            /* Do other stuff */
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [case guards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#case-guards) and [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) like this:

```cs
bool HashMatches(int TargetHash) => hash == TargetHash;

switch (true):
{
case true when HashMatches(state1):
    //DoStuff
    break;
case true when HashMatches(state2):
    //Other stuff
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether you can simplify it or not, it depends on the similarities between your "DoStuff", "Other Stuff", "Next Stuff", and  "You other stuffs"

1. Suppose your `Stuff` "family members" are actually:

   ```
   int stuffAction(int state){
       int modified_state;
       //do something on state and modified state
       return modified_state;
   }
   ```

   Then, obviously you `Stuffs` can be simplified by using **function**, just as shown above. It can be simplified likewise as long as your `Stuff` have same function with different argument.
2. Also, if you `Stuffs` are in the form different functions but having the same input parameters, you can create `Dictionary` of `delegates` (see `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Delegate>`) such that when you can call the `Stuff` you simply need to do

   ```
   dic[state](input parameters here)
   ```

   instead of using if-else or switch

There might be some possibilities where your code cannot be simplified further, but the bottom line is, as I said earlier, depend on the similarities between your `Stuff`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only with if-else if:

```
int state1 = Animator.StringToHash("State1");
int state2 = Animator.StringToHash("State2");
int hash = _myAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).shortNameHash;
if (hash == state1) {
    //DoStuff
}
else if (hash == state2) {
    //Other stuff
}
```

Comment: OP specifically mentioned not wanting to have a 'big if-else block' which is what this amounts to.  Personally I don't see the issue and would probably do it this way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional operator to accomplish a pseudo switch statement, though it is actually an if-else block.  This assumes your "do stuff" sections can be wrapped in methods returning a common type.  Assuming `DoState1` and `DoState2` both return `void`...

```
hash == state1 ? DoState1()
: hash == state2 ? DoState2()
: throw new NotImplementedException();
```

if you wanted to return a value... change the Do methods to return the same type (e.g. bool) and assign it to a variable.

```
bool result 
  = hash == state1 ? DoState1()
  : hash == state2 ? DoState2()
  : false;
```

It feels and reads very much like a switch statement or expression.  The only limitation is you must encapsulate your code block into a method, which is a good practice anyway.

This approach is also great for LINQ as it converts to a SQL CASE statement (for EFC7+ and SQL Server)

```
.Select(x => new Dto
{
   RecordExists = x.Source.RecordExists is null ? "UNKNOWN"
                : x.Source.RecordExists > 1 ? "MANY"
                : x.Source.RecordExists == 1 ? "ONE"
                : "NO"
});
```